# Newly installed Sublime Text 3 package commands do not show up in the command pallette

Tags: sublimetext3

I've installed a couple of Sublime Text 3 packages recently and have noticed that some of the commands that should be available via the package do not show in the command palette, though other commands for the same package do.

Specifically, I installed the package [PHPCompanion](https://github.com/erichard/SublimePHPCompanion) and all of the commands show in the pallette but `insert_php_constructor_property`:

[image]

Or the package [PHP Getters and Setters](https://github.com/francodacosta/sublime-php-getters-setters), none of the commands are available.

I'm actually not even sure where to start as far as troubleshooting this. Most of the links I've found so far say "uninstall the package and reinstall it" (which I've done) and "make sure the packages aren't in your Ignore Packages preference properties" (which I've confirmed).

Is there something else I can do to figure out why the commands are not available?

Comment: You have rebooted your Mac I assume?

Comment: Yep :/ could it be a conflict with another package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the issue (though I still don't know what the issue was).

I deleted the Sublime Text **app** and installed a new version from the sublime home page. After launching the new version the commands started showing up.

Note that I only deleted the app itself, I did not delete the Application Support or Preference files. This means all of my previously installed packages, themes, and even session were all still in place.

Hopefully this helps anyone else that runs into the same issue.